# Send user a message if deployed

Tags: firebase

Can I send my users of my web-app a short message if I deployed the app again each time?

So I mean if I run `firebase deploy`, after the finish I want to send the users a short message that the app got updated.

Can I do this with `google-cloud-messaging`?

Comment: Sounds feasible, although I'd recommend using [**Firebase** Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) which is replacing GCM. I'd say you give it a try, and report back if you have a specific problem implementing it.

Comment: ohh yes I mean Firebase Cloud Messaging. I will try it later